# Run bash command with current URL as parameter from Firefox and/or safari

Tags: automator, bash, firefox

I'd like to be able, without much hassle, add a video to my Miro Download-queue.

From bash I can do this by entering

```
open -a Miro.app http://vimeo.com/24398084
```

Now I'd like to do this from within Firefox, preferrably a one-click approach. Is there a firefox addon I could use? Some automator mechanism I could trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an automator service like this:

[image]

The service receives no input. It gets the URL of the current page in Safari, and passes it as the argument to `open -a Miro.app`.

You could then assign it a keyboard shortcut, et voilà.

Comment: +1 but can you use Firefox in automator to do this?

Comment: @macaco If you're willing to use two keystrokes, then yes. Service receives selected text in any application. Then drop the first action. To invoke, press Command-L then the shortcut for the service.